# NodeJs require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm trying for the first time NodeJs, I installed NodeJs, npm and all needed modules for my project. Now I want to run it on my website (still on localhost). But when I open console there is error saying *Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at HTMLDocument.* And then specification on which line in code I used require.
It is simple line `const bodyParser = require("body-parser");` but on the website it does not work. Is there something more I need to do?

Comment: How do you execute your javascript code after you're done writing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: I don't. I thought that website would take care of it, just like with other javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

`require` is only used from server-side and not usable on browser. And please know that `NodeJs` is JavaScript RunTime for server-side programming.

Answer (score 0):

[yash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12364558/yash) is right.
If you want to import a module on front-end side, you can use ES6's [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). All modern browsers support it.
But if you want to import in oldest browsers too, read about [browserify](http://browserify.org/) where you can use special `require` function.